# Dynamic JMS uri and dynamic broker url with Apache Camel

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

I send messages to **ActiveMQ** with **Apache Camel**. I'm using recipientList method because I need a dynamic URI.

In runtime, i have to change the broker URL. I have the following problem : when I change the connectionFactory (new broker URL), it is not taken into account by the producer. However, when I use .to method instead of recipientList method, it works fine. I also have a jms consumer which takes into account well the modification.

My route builder :

```
from(JMS_OUTBOUND)
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader(JMS_FROM_HEADER, idOrganisation);    
                    long fileSize = (long) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileLength");
                    if(fileSize > 50000000) {
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("tooHeavyFile", true);
                        String parentPath = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileParent");
                        String tooHeavyFileDirectory = parentPath + "/too_heavy_file/";
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("tooHeavyFilePath", tooHeavyFileDirectory);
                    } else {
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("tooHeavyFile", false);
                    }
                }
            })
            .choice()
                .when(header("tooHeavyFile").isEqualTo(false))
                    .recipientList(simple("mybrokerjms:queue:${header.jms-to}?mapJmsMessage=false"))
                    .end()
                .otherwise()
                   .recipientList(simple("file://${header.tooHeavyFilePath}"))
            .routeId(JMS_OUTBOUND_ID);
```

How I update the broker URL :

```
context.removeComponent("mybrokerjms");
context.stopRoute(JmsRouteBuilder.JMS_INBOUND_ID);
context.stopRoute(JmsRouteBuilder.JMS_OUTBOUND_ID);
context.removeRoute(JmsRouteBuilder.JMS_INBOUND_ID);
context.removeRoute(JmsRouteBuilder.JMS_OUTBOUND_ID); 

List<Hub> hubList = hubBoundary.findAll();
if(hubList != null && hubList.size() > 0) {

        Hub hub = hubList.get(0);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://" + hub.getAddress() + ":" + hub.getPort());
        context.addComponent("mybrokerjms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

        Configuration configuration = configurationBoundary.find("ID_ORGANIZATION");
        if(configuration != null) {
            String idClient = configurationBoundary.find("ID_ORGANIZATION").getProperty();
            context.addRoutes(new JmsRouteBuilder(idClient));           
    }
}
```

Camel version : 2.15.1.